# Trying to Add a Reference to Visual Studio Project Suddenly Throws an Exception

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to ADD a REFERENCE to any Visual Studio project...I am suddenly getting the following exception:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

- This happens across ALL projects regardless of whether they are source-controlled (or not)

SIDE NOTE:
I did recently install `Xamarin` on a `SEPARATE PROJECT` in another `TFS SOLUTION`

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR**:

1. Delete all *.suo files
2. Delete all *.user files
3. Wiped the TFS Workspace & done a FORCE GET

Nothing has worked

Comment: What kind of reference are you trying to add? Are you saying that you're adding a project reference to a project in a solution or are you saying that you're trying to add a reference (such as a DLL) to a project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The FIRST TIME you get this error message you'll get a window with a reference to the following file:

- **ActivityLog.xml**: This file contains information about the underlying error.

If you ignore the message & click away from the initial dialog, THE ERROR GETS SUPPRESSED and is replaced with:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

If you look in this file you will see the error.  This particular exception was was caused by:

- **Microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.IVsReferenceManager2**
- Within the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll** library.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/4eea5785-0a83-4389-89e3-209a5a4432c0/referencemanagerpackage-fails-to-install-vs-2017-community-edition?forum=vssetup) helped me solve the issue!

**THE FIX IS:**

1. Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" as an Administraor
2. CD into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"
3. Run "gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll"
4. After a restart, it all worked well.